# Why are my plots not appearing properly?

Tags: texstudio, r

I got a new laptop last week and installed TexStudio and TexShop. When using TexStudio, my pdf plots from R aren't displaying properly. An example is below. This is it in TexStudio:

[image]

But this is the original plot:[image]

The final pdf document that TexStudio creates of my report has the plot included properly, but in the TexStudio preview window it isn't. This makes it more time consuming to check my plots.

Comment: I'm guessing that fonts are not being embedded in the PDF, similar to the problem at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/233#issuecomment-404577908